# Вывод подкатегорий которые принадлежат определённой категории в выпадающем списке Django Admin

Tags: python, django

Я изучаю django и у меня проблемы. В административной панели django, когда я добавляю продукт и выбираю категорию и подкатегорию, я вижу все подкатегории всех категорий. Это проблема, потому что в моем приложении может быть много похожих подкатегорий.[image: Картинка!!!!]

Вот мой models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField('Название',max_length=255)
   slug = models.SlugField('Ссылка', unique=True)


class Sub_Category(models.Model):

  category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  name = models.CharField('Название', max_length=255)
  slug = models.SlugField('Ссылка', unique=True)



class Product(models.Model):

  category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  sub_category = models.ForeignKey(Sub_Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  title = models.CharField('Название товара:', max_length=50)
  slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

Comment: **в моем приложении может быть много похожих подкатегорий...** избавьтесь от одинаковых категорий...

Comment: @Jack_oS, а нормальное решение есть этому?

Comment: а почему бы не обойтись одной моделью `Category`, а конкретно в ней сделать связь на саму себя что бы была возможность добавлять подкатегории? Таким образом вы сможете добавлять подкатегории даже для подкатегорий))

Comment: @5c0rp хочется сделать именно отдельным классом, если есть такая возможность вообще

Comment: Прочитай эту статью, думаю это то что тебе нужно https://betterprogramming.pub/optimizing-django-admin-6a1187ddbb09